# Android logging in native code not showing

Tags: android, c, eclipse, android-ndk, android-logcat

I am using the `android/log.h` methods in my native code to write to the android log (`__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, ANDROID_DEBUG_TAG, message);`). I am also doing logging in the Java code. However, when running, only the log messages from the Java code is displayed in the logger. What could cause these problems?

I have set all the required info in the android-manifest, and the rest of the native code runs fine in my android app. I don't get any errors or anything either, it just seems silently ignored.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I use `__android_log_print` in my NDK code and that works fine. I don't know the difference between the two methods off the top of my head, but give that a try (it takes the same arguments).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use __android_log_print(...), include the log library in your Android makefile

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. These are the details: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#mnu